# Expanding a div with content without moving elements below it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-position

I have an element on the page which, when it is hovered over, expands and reveals some previously hidden text within it. The problem is that when the element expands, it moves other content below it. I tried to use `position:absolute`, but it has not achieved the desired effect.

```css
.col {
  padding: 20px;
}

.col:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.revealOnHover {
  display: none;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

#block1:hover .revealOnHover,
#block2:hover .revealOnHover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="block1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=1">
      <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b></p>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: red;"></i>
      <p class="revealOnHover">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col" id="block2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=1">
      <p><b>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</b></p>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: red;"></i>
      <p class="revealOnHover">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="font-weight: bold; margin: 0 auto; margin-right: 2rem; color: #FFF">Click here</button></a>
    <a href="https://agoria.be" target="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="font-weight: bold; margin: 0 auto; margin-right: 2rem; color: #FFF">Click here</button></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

My Code: https://codepen.io/eren5897/pen/GRqgOyd

Comment: What's the intended behaviour for the buttons? To go in front of the expanded `<div>`? Behind it? If they don't move then there will be unavoidable overlap.

Comment: The buttons should stay behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not far off actually. `position:absolute` is the way to go, but you need a few additional styles to make it work, mainly in order to correctly position it and make it share the background color of its parent.

```css
.col {
  padding: 20px;
}

.col:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.revealOnHover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: inherit;
}

#block1:hover .revealOnHover,
#block2:hover .revealOnHover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="block1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=1">
      <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b></p>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: red;"></i>
      <p class="revealOnHover">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col" id="block2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=1">
      <p><b>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</b></p>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: red;"></i>
      <p class="revealOnHover">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="font-weight: bold; margin: 0 auto; margin-right: 2rem; color: #FFF">Click here</button></a>
    <a href="https://agoria.be" target="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="font-weight: bold; margin: 0 auto; margin-right: 2rem; color: #FFF">Click here</button></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add min-height to your row class

Your class becomes

```
.row {
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
min-height: 317PX;}
```

Comment: This solution won't work if my second div has more text.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding

```
.row {
  min-height: 20rem
}
```

This makes sure that they don't move when the divs are being expanded.

Comment: This solution won't work if my second div has more text.

Comment: Then use more rem e.g. `max-heigt: 40rem;`?